# Can Azure pipelines get source from TFS Service Connection?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-pipelines

I have pipelines in Azure DevOps working with Windows Self hosted agent, I currently get source code from external Git but I also need to get source code from internal TFS 2018 server.

I created a service connection, I saw that I can specify it as an Azure subscription name in tasks that deploys but I can't see how to get source code, I have this UI when I create a YAML pipeline but there is not either any TFS option in classic mode:

[image]

Should I have a Service or TFS option  in there ?
Thanks.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I had to stop working for few days, I don't fully have my answer, I will explain in each answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service connection named **other git** and use this service connection to get source code from TFS 2018. Here is my sample:

1. Create a Personal access token in TFS 2018.
2. Create a service connection named other git. The Git repository URL is the URL when you open the TFS 2018 repository.

If you are using git as source control, the format of the URL is `http://{server:port}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/{repo name}`

If you are using TFVC as source control, the format of the URL is `http://{server:port}/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project name}/_versionControl`
or `http://{server:port}/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project name}`

Please enter the Personal access token you created in the Password/Token filed.

[image]

3.Create a pipeline and choose other git as source.  You can choose an already created service connection or create a new one.
[image]

Now you can use the repository in TFS 2018 as the source of this pipeline.

Comment: This seems to be the closest answer but the "Git repository URL", is it an optional thing ?  When I open my repo in a browser, I have: https://tfs.my.cie/defaultcollection/MyProject/_versionControl

Comment: Ok, I created a service connection to https://tfs.my.cie/defaultcollection/MyProject/ witjh a PAT and I am able to connect to it from the pipeline

Comment: @ClaudeVernier  Glad to hear your good news. Both  tfs.my.cie/defaultcollection/MyProject/_versionControl and  tfs.my.cie/defaultcollection/MyProject are working fine on my side. I add more details about Git repository URL in my answer. You could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Comment: I created a new PAT from TFS.
I updated my Service Connection with this PAT and this URL:
 https://tfs.xxx.com/defaultcollection/{Project}/_versionControl
I updated the pipeline, I have no Branch so I used "master".
The pipeline ended with 504 Connection Timed Out.

Comment: I am wondering if it can be linked to how we use TFS.
When I open the above URL, I have a screen like in this image (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cJowM2r4CBkw50ceeholB6FWbRtipaNg/view?usp=sharing).  It is a mess in there, the project I need is hidden in sub-folders.
Is that an issue? Must I specify the full path or simply the URL above so it will fetch everything under {Project} and I specify the full path only when I build ?

Comment: Now I see in the logs, this error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to tfs.xxx.com:443 

Might be just a security issue, it happened to me a lot.
I'll check with security team but if you could tell me if I'm write about the branch and the full path, it would help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach if you are looking at TFVC:

- Go to project settings --> Repositories --> Create Repo. Select TFVC
  [image]
- After you create the TFVC repo, from the build you should be able to find the option:
  [image]

Comment: I understand this is to create a TFS repo on Azure, is that right ?  I need to access the TFS server on premises.  I tried to create one and got a 500 error.